# authentication system using token in nodejs vuejs app?

Tags: node.js, authentication, vue.js

I have built an spa using nodejs and vuejs i want to add an authentication system on it, but i haven't done it before hence need some guidance.

the flow will be like :
1) admin will create the profile of the user 
2) An email will be automatically sent to the user using sendgrid
3) the email consits of an url with token which expires in 24 hrs the user when click in specific time will be routed to a page where they can create a new password
4) i was planning to use passport for authentication in my app

Is this the right way to do?, also how do i send the token with url and authenticate when i the user clicks

Comment: i was working on the same kind of project and glad that you also work on the same. Did you happen to find the solution for this authentication system? if possible can you help me the any git repo?

Comment: Yes, I found the solution for the same though I cannot share the repo with you as it was a commercial project, You can use an email delivery system to push the emails and web tokens for the token system, you can also use passport library which works like a charm for the same. Let me know if you need any more help

Answer (score 0):

Your flow sounds right to me. You can use a token in the query params of the url like:

`http://yoursite.com/user/verify/?token=<some-token>`

or even in the url like:

`http://yoursite.com/user/verify/<some-token>`

Then in server, you can extract the token from the url, verify it, and act on it. [JWT](https://jwt.io/) is a good scheme to have data embedded in tokens.

Comment: thank you for the reply , will look into JWT where can i find examples with the similar working model . @ tbking

Comment: I can't recall any github repo that I can link to, which shows this model. But I've used this model in my own projects, and made it from scratch, an email module, a jwt module, and all. If you think about it, it's pretty straight-forward.

Comment: happy to help !